# How to use splunk-logging nodeJs module with typeScript (node v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, splunk

im trying to make splunk logging tpo worth with my typescript code (nodeJS v14). I found the [documentation](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-javascript-logging) that mention this example:

```
var SplunkLogger = require("splunk-logging").Logger;

var config = {
    token: "your-token-here",
    url: "https://splunk.local:8088"
};

var Logger = new SplunkLogger(config);

var payload = {
    // Message can be anything; doesn't have to be an object
    message: {
        temperature: "70F",
        chickenCount: 500
    }
};

console.log("Sending payload", payload);
Logger.send(payload, function(err, resp, body) {
    // If successful, body will be { text: 'Success', code: 0 }
    console.log("Response from Splunk", body);
});
```

The problem I'm having is that 1) I'm new to JS and Typescript and 2 I can "translate" this to type script where I usually use `import {XXXXX} from "XXXXXX"` and the use `let` and `const`, etc...

Any idea or guide will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add `@types/splunk-logging`

```js
import { Logger as SplunkLogger } from 'splunk-logging';

export const log = () => {

  const config = {
      token: "your-token-here",
      url: "https://splunk.local:8088"
  };

  const Logger = new SplunkLogger(config);

  const payload = {
      // Message can be anything; doesn't have to be an object
      message: {
          temperature: "70F",
          chickenCount: 500
      }
  };

  console.log("Sending payload", payload);
  Logger.send(payload, (err, resp, body)=> {
      // If successful, body will be { text: 'Success', code: 0 }
      console.log("Response from Splunk", body);
  });
};
```